# UML diagram - method with multiple arguments?

Tags: java, uml

Say for example I have a method(constructor) as follows:

```
public animals(String a, String b, String c, int d){
```

When creating a written UML diagram, would I have to write String three times within the parameters or just once?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be written as:

```
+animals(a:String, b:String, c:String, d:int)
```

By the way, your constructor should have the exact name of the class, and that must be in TitleCase, and should be singular (recommendation). Therefore, the recommended name here is: "Animal"

Comment: Yea sorry I wasn't really thinking about that when making this, just made up a quick example. Thanks.

Comment: That should be fine Mark :)